# Issue with preg_match_all Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So my project currently has the following line of code in it.

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', $content, $match)) {
```

Now the problem is, if the users name has punctuation (e.g. ?Dennis or -Damo ) it won't allow the @ tag to pick up the username, e.g. @-Damo or @?Dennis won't tag the user (with code following this line.

Any idea how I modify the above so punctuation is allowed after the @ sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture everything after the @, then you could go with ...

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(.+)/', $content, $match)) {
```

That basically doesn't care what comes after the @.

If you want specific characters, then maybe ...

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@([A-Za-z0-9?-]+)/', $content, $match)) {
```

Watch out for the last - in that class. It isn't the same as the one that's between A-Z, a-z or 0-9

If you want the punctuation ONLY after the @ (but optional) then

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@([?-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)/', $content, $match)) {
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: So with that first one `if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(.+)/', $content, $match)) {` would it count everything after it e.g. "@-Damo hello" or just the "@-Damo" bit?

Comment: Everything. https://regex101.com is a good tool to help explain what a regex actually is doing and allows you to throw in test data to see if you get matches or not.

Regexes can be VERY picky. If you want everything upto white space, then

    if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@([^\S]+)/', $content, $match)) {

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code and it did it perfectly!

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<FullMention>@(?<UsernameOnly>[a-zA-Z0-9,\-_]{1,}))/', $content, $match)) {
    foreach($match['UsernameOnly'] as $usr) {
        -code here-
    }
}
```